# Leading Zero when extract Day and Month

Tags: postgresql

Hello i'm trying to extract current day and month in a query. This query is filling table from csv file.
the file is named like this:

> LOG_01_01_2018.csv

My query search for file:

> LOG_1_1_2018.csv

With no Zero in front day and month. **How to add Zero numbers?**

Here is the code:

```
 execute format ($f$COPY tmp_x FROM 'D:\Programs\PS\download_files_from_ftp_avtomat\files\LOG_%s_%s_%s.csv' 
(header, FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',', NULL ' ', ENCODING 'WIN1251');
$f$,extract(day from now()),extract(month from now()),extract(year from now()));
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One option uses `LPAD`:

```
execute format ($f$COPY tmp_x FROM 'D:\Programs\PS\download_files_from_ftp_avtomat\files\LOG_%s_%s_%s.csv'
(header, FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',', NULL ' ', ENCODING 'WIN1251');
$f$,
    lpad(extract(day from now())::text, 2, '0'),
    lpad(extract(month from now())::text, 2, '0'),
    extract(year from now()));
```

The year would always be a fixed width four digit number, unless you plan to work with data which existed before computers were around.

Comment: lpad(extract('hour' from time_stamp),2,0) as event_hour  -- how can we convert for hive understandable ?

Answer (score 5):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

`extract(field from timestamp)` returns `double precision`, so you either `lpad` zero to it (making the value text), or just use `to_char` with data mask, eg:

```
t=# select extract(day from now()), to_char(now(),'MM'),extract(year from now());
 date_part | to_char | date_part
-----------+---------+-----------
        19 | 01      |      2018
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer once again :) I have errors with your example. But when using lpad from the example in the second answer it worked instantly. May be i`m doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Looks shorter to use to_char():

```
SELECT to_char(now(),'DD')||'/'||to_char(now(),'MM')||'/'||to_char(now(),'YYYY')
```

Comment: You could just do `SELECT to_char(now(),'DD/MM/YYYY')`.